# External editing of .tiff, retaining georeferencing?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, geotiff-tiff

Is there any way I can reduce the colours of a TIFF to make conversion to polygon more efficient. There's quite a bit of artification on my original and I'd like to reduce it to 2 colours before the conversion (which I have done, however once re-saved it loses the referencing).

Reduced coluor image:

[image]

Original TIFF in QGIS

[image]

Output polygon with solid white removed

[image]

Comment: Write a VRT to preserve the metadata, or try Manifold which always treats tifs as geo, and has image edit tools.

Comment: try gdal_translate.exe -ot byte

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS, you can use the raster calculator to reclass your raster in a binary way:

```
("<layername>@1">100)*100
```

will set all cells with values greater 100 to 100, all other cells to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to reclass it into two classes using [r.reclass](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.reclass.html) in the GRASS toolbox, then do the standard raster-to-vector conversion.